# Paypal subscr_id not working

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I have finally got my paypal IPN working....what a nightmare.
The only variable that kicks up an error is the subscribtion ID.

Every other variable i gather is fine, just not this and i don't know why.

Here is what i have:

```
$firstname = $myPost['first_name'];
$lastname = $myPost['last_name'];
$itemname = $myPost['item_name'];
$payment_amount = $myPost['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $myPost['mc_currency'];
$tx_id = $myPost['ipn_track_id'];
$sub_id = $myPost['subscr_id']; 
$receiver_email = $myPost['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $myPost['payer_email'];
$businessemail = " ";   
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
```

My question is why doesn't it work? It is the same layout as all the other variables....and i followed paypals list on variable names so it sshoudl work.

What I get on my web server as an error is this:

```
[17-May-2015 14:59:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: subscr_id in /home/thirdist/public_html/IPNtest.php on line 110
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the subscriber id is set?

Output all POST variables to a file and check the values you are receiving.
You can do a `var_dump($_POST)` but since this is a postback script and you cant really watch it running, try outputting the datas to a file and test a postback.

`file_put_contents('data.txt', print_r($_POST, true));`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, the program seems to dump the info ok, so the data is getting sent. I just seem to be getting an error log created.
I noticed too, that the error changes between 2 different variables....at random it seems, but the data still gets back to where I need it.....most of the time.

Comment: Then you should probably go like, `if(isset($variable))` do the rest. So it doesnt raise an error/warning if the data is not being sent.